# QGIS Layer Window Layer Selection Using Numeric Keys

Tags: qgis, vector-layer

I know that the layer is selected using the number keys in the QGIS layer window.

For example,

[image]

Press the number key 1 to select the first layer in the order of the layer window,(pano_bf)

Press the number key 2 to select the second layer.(pano_af)

Up to qgis 2.8.9, selection seems to be made with number keys, but after that version, the first and second layers are not selected with number keys 1 and 2, but it seems to be selected from the third layer with number keys 3.

**Can I solve the problem that the first and second layers cannot be selected with number keys 1 and 2?**